# Given $f(x)=\frac{\left(\cos x-1\right)}{x\sin x}, x \in (-\pi,\pi)$. Find $f(0)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Given $$f(x)=\frac{\left(\cos x-1\right)}{x\sin x}, \quad x\in (-\pi,\pi), $$ find $f(0)$. It's obvious that we can't divide by $0$, why is $f(0)=-0.5?%$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, $f(0)=0/0$ is undefined. It is the *limit point*, or *closure* of the function at $x=0$, that is defined as $-0.5$. The limit is found by rendering

$(\cos x-1)(\cos x+1)=\cos^2x-1=-\sin^2x$

and applying the $\sin x/x\to1$ limit.

Answer (score 0):

**If only** $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, the $f(0)=\lim_{x\rightarrow =0} f(x)=L$.
Use $\sin x=x- x^3/ 3!+...$ and $\cos x=1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!+...$
$$L=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\cos x-1}{x \sin x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{1-x^2/2!+x^4/4!-1}{x^2+O(x^4)}=-1/2.$$